# Start SUM in Excel From Exact Cell

Tags: excel

[image]

I have Excel table like this. How do I sum all the prices starting from the red line like the arrow shows? So when I add something above the red line it keeps summing from the line below?

Comment: Convert it to a range

Comment: Can you explain me a bit more?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't a very helpful comment. I was just saying that if your data was an ordinary Excel range rather than a table, there wouldn't have been a problem. I will post a possible workaround for it in case you want to keep your data as a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data was an ordinary Excel range, there wouldn't be a problem because as extra rows are inserted the formula would be modified to allow for them. If you want to keep your data as a table, here is possible workaround.

I suggest adding an extra column to label your data, so I have marked the data that you want to sum with an "x".

In the totals row, under Amount, instead of using SUM you use SUMIF just to get the sum of the rows that are labelled with an "x":_

```
=SUMIF([Label],"x",[Amount])
```

So if extra rows are added with a blank Label, they won't be included in the sum.

You might already have something like a date that you could use to select the ones you want to sum instead.

Alternatively there is nothing to stop you using an ordinary Excel range like

```
=SUM(A7:A13)
```

or see @Jeeped's excellent suggestion below.

[image]

Comment: As an array formula `=SUM(INDEX([amount], MATCH(0, LEN([amount]), 0)):INDEX([amount], MATCH(1E+99, [amount])))`

Comment: That is really elegant. I was also going to make the trivial point that there is nothing to stop you putting an ordinary reference within a table as another way to do it but that probably isn't the answer OP wants.